# Task ContinueWith() Not Updating Cursor on UI Thread

Tags: c#, task

I'm working on a WPF app and I simply want to alter the cursor before and after the task runs. I have this code:

```
this.Cursor = Cursors.Wait;

Task.Factory.StartNew(() => PerformMigration(legacyTrackerIds)).ContinueWith(_ => this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow);
```

The cursor indeed changes to the wait cursor, but it doesn't change back to the arrow when the task is done. If I put a breakpoint in the ContinueWith() method, it gets hit. But the cursor doesn't change back to an arrow. Why?

This was the old way I was trying it. The cursor changed back to an arrow, but I don't want to Wait() for the task.

```
this.Cursor = Cursors.Wait;

Task.Factory.StartNew(() => PerformMigration(legacyTrackerIds)).Wait();

this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The cursor change needs to be done on the UI thread. You can either use the the [overload of ContinueWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321428) that takes a task scheduler:

```
var uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext(); 

Task.Factory
  .StartNew(() => PerformMigration(legacyTrackerIds))
  .ContinueWith(_ => this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow, uiScheduler);
```

Or use the [Dispatcher.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx) method:

```
Task.Factory
  .StartNew(() => PerformMigration(legacyTrackerIds))
  .ContinueWith(_ => { Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow; }); });
```

Comment: Shouldn't I get an exception then?

Comment: @BobHorn You very possibly are, but since it's in a background thread it's only bringing down that thread, not the whole application.

Comment: When I try the first suggestion, I get a compile-time error: `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type`.

Comment: @BobHorn You really shouldn't use that method anyway.  Tasks were designed such that the second method is preferred.

Comment: I just tried the second option and that worked. While I'd be curious to know why I'm getting the compile-time error with the first option, I still got things working, so thanks!

Comment: @BobHorn Answer updated. Although Servy is correct, using the overload of ContinueWith that takes a TaskScheduler is preferable (as such, I have placed it first).

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use the correct synchronization context:

```
this.Cursor = Cursors.Wait; 

var uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()); 

Task.Factory.StartNew(() => PerformMigration(legacyTrackerIds))
            .ContinueWith(_ => this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow, uiScheduler);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the continuation needs to run in the UI thread.  Currently it's being done in a background thread.

Add `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` to the second parameter of `ContinueWith` to have it run in the UI thread.